# Javascript getFullYear is returning wrong year

Tags: javascript, angular

I am trying to get the current year as follows

```js
var d = new Date();
console.log("Date = " + d); //  Fri Apr 16 2021 20:00:00 GMT-0400 (Eastern Daylight Time)
var n = d.getFullYear();
console.log("Current Year = " + n); //2021
```

This is returning 2021 instead of 2020

I am using EST. How can I get the correct year?

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Have you checked what your system time is set as?

Comment: Works fine for me too.

Comment: i figured it is a local setting. How can I check what the system time is?I am using Webstorm

Comment: which os are you using ? windows ? linux ? mac ?

Comment: since new Date results in `Fri Apr 16 2021 20:00:00 GMT-0400` you can easily see that the date on your computer is set to `Friday, April 16, 2021` - it's odd that the time is **exactly** 8pm too - does it happen with the snippet as well?

Comment: @Mary - what year is displayed if you click on "Run Code Snippet"

Comment: Run Coe Snippet returns the corrcet values, current year = 2020

Answer (score 0):

`new Date()` gets data from your computer. Verify if the date on your computer is the correct date. You can change this in your computer settings.

> Control Panel\Clock and Region

Comment: I am using Windows1- and the Date is correct on my machine10/22 and the time zone is (UTC-05:00 )Eastern Time (US & Canada). I am not sure where it is getting the GMT time from

Comment: @Mary - GMT time is from your computer too obviously in April it's Daylight Time, hence UTC-04:00  (or GMT-04:00 same thing) as opposed to UTC-05:00 (or GMT-05:00)

Comment: I am running this from WebStorm Terminal window and it is showing as 2021. However, when I try to run it on the browser, I correctly see 2020.

Comment: @Mary - So, is it ALWAYS 8pm  Apr 16 2021?

Comment: Yes! It seems to always be April 16 8 PM 2021, when running from Webstorm!

Comment: I would suggest using a different Terminal then.